# Использование одного фрагмента много раз

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, fragment-manager

Есть класс `myFragment` типа `Fragment`. В `MainActivity` имеется `TabLayout` и `ViewPager`.

Нужно добавить в `ViewPager` адаптер, добавить много фрагментов. У каждого фрагмента меняется только Адаптер от `ListView`. Пробывал передать при создании фрагмента параметр и по этому параметру ставить определенный адаптер для `ListView` вот код. Но каждый раз показывает 1 и тот же адаптер, хотя сделал в кнопке чтобы показывал Id, который я помещал в аргументы, показывает на каждой странице разный т.е. свой положенный id.
Как быть.

MainActivity

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

int i=1;
while(i<114){
    adapter.addFragment(new myFragment().setId(i),String.valueOf(i));
    i++;
}

viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

myFragment класс:

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment{

     public myFragment setId(int myId){
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("myId", myId);
            myFragment f = new myFragment();
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        idAdapter = getArguments().getInt("myId");
        switch(idAdapter){
        case 1:
            // Присваиваю адаптер к ListView с определенным курсором.
            break;

        case 2:
            // Присваиваю адаптер к ListView с определенным курсором.
            break;
        }
```

... OnCreateView

Comment: Ну... Видать в самом адаптере для списков что-то не так... В вашем коде ошибок не видно.

Comment: А где в адаптере может быть ошибка? Просто он одно и тоже в каждой странице тусует. В чем копать?

Comment: Ну... Может вы одни и теже данные получаете во всех случаях...

Comment: Не, этого не может быть) Там все от главного Id зависит. У меня стоит там CursorLoader и он static может из за этого?

Comment: Да, возможно из-за этого. Статик один и принимает значение последнее кое вы ему назначили.

Comment: так CursorLoader вроде не работает если он не static, да он должен был последнее значение брать, но он берет то на которую я нажму. До этого у меня есть меню, где выбираешь пункт, и попадаешь на активити где эти фрагменты с TabLayout, так во всех фрагментах в адаптере бывает то значение которое я выбираю в главном меню

Comment: В Ansdroid SDK нет ни одного класса который бы не работал без static